# How do I convert code implementing hook_init()?

Tags: hooks

Looking on Drupal.org API, I noticed that [`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is not documented for Drupal 8. Looking at the change records, I found [Bootstrap hooks no longer exist](https://drupal.org/node/2062965), which points to [Get rid of all 'bootstrap' hooks](https://drupal.org/node/1888734), where the bootstrap hooks are said to be `hook_boot()` and `hook_exit()`; nothing is said about `hook_init()`.

I searched for *hook_init* in Drupal 8 source, and I found the following code. The first one is a reference to `hook_init()` made in a comment; the other two seem a `hook_init()` implementation, but they both get a parameter I am not expecting.

```php
function overlay_enable() {
  if (strpos(current_path(), 'admin/modules') === 0) {
    // Flag for a redirect to <front>#overlay=admin/modules on hook_init().
    $_SESSION['overlay_enable_redirect'] = 1;
  }
}
```

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function phptemplate_init($template) {
  $file = dirname($template->filename) . '/' . $template->name . '.theme';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;
  }
}
```

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function twig_init($template) {
  $file = dirname($template->filename) . '/' . $template->name . '.theme';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;
  }
}
```

I also looked for any function invoking `hook_init()` but I didn't find any.

How do I convert Drupal 7 code implementing `hook_init()` to code running on Drupal 8/9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this has changed since this question was last answered. But I think the preferred approach to replacing what is going on in `hook_init` is to create an event subscriber, and adding to the 'request'. Here is how you do that for those that may find it useful.

Example services.yml

```
services:
  init_subscriber:
    class:   Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MyModuleSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_user'] // <- optional args
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber} // <- Required Tag
```

Then you would implement the `EventSubscriberInterface` (new file in the `src/EventSubscriber` directory) and in the implemented method `getSubscribedEvents` you can do something like...

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('initializeMyModule');
  return $events;
}
```

And add the method accordingly

```
/**
 * MyModule
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
 *   The event to process.
 */
public function initializeMyModule(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  $request = $event->getRequest();   
  ...
}
```

Comment: How to use ['#attached]['js] in function initializeMyModule? SInce there is no $var, $page or somether argument in the function.

Comment: @neha – You don't. This answer copes with how to replace hook init for more advanced stuff. But for attaching libraries you use `hook_page_attachments` or `hook_page_attachments_alter`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `hook_init()` is not used in Drupal 8. If you need `drupal_add_js()` or `drupal_add_css()` you can use `hook_page_build()` instead, which is also useful for that in Drupal 7.

For example, CSS styles and  JavaScript code can be added to `hook_page_build()` using `$page['#attached']`.

```php
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE');
$page['#attached']['js'][$path . '/my_module.js'] = array('scope' => 'footer');
$page['#attached']['css'][$path . '/my_module.base.css'] = array('every_page' => TRUE);
```

If you need to do more complex listening on the request/response, you can define an event listener as documented on [hook_init() removed](https://drupal.org/node/2013014).

Comment: Appears that hook_page_build isn't a thing in D8 anymore?

Answer (score 5):

`hook_page_build()` has been deprecated in favor of [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.9.x) as documented on [Added hook_page_attachments(_alter)() and removed hook_page_build/alter()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755).

For example, to attach a library to every page, the hook implementation would be similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'modulename/libraryname';
}
```

`libraryname` is the name of the library, defined in your module's mymodule.libraries.yml.