# Hook on every page or route

Tags: 8, hooks

What hook is run on every page before `hook_preprocess_page()`?

Comment: Consider using an event subscriber as explained in this change record: [hook_init() removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014)

Comment: Wild guess: `hook_preprocess_html()`.

Comment: But tbh, please try to provide a little bit more info. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Depending on that giving you just another hook (if exists) might just be wrong. Please also see [How to ask a good question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apart from that you are also able to change the implementation order of modules targeting a specific hook.

Comment: Brilliant answer on how to replace hook init with an event subscribers: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/173920/15055

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert code implementing hook\_init()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/how-do-i-convert-code-implementing-hook-init)